# Search for attribute in xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I have tried many different methods but not luck. All I am trying to do is identify the domain of the current URL and pull out an value from an XML file based on the domain.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

merchants.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
  <merchant id="1">
    <domain>http://www.amazon.com</domain>
    <affiliate>1</affiliate>
  </merchant>
</catalog>
```

popup.js

```
function ReadXML() {
    try {
        var xmlPath = "merchants.xml";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: xmlPath,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXML
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error while reading XML; Description – " + e.description);
    }
}

function parseXML(xml) {
    var $merchant = $(xml).find('domain').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == "http://www.amazon.com";
    }).closest('domain');
    var affiliate = $('affiliate', $domain).text();

    if(window.location.hostname.indexOf("http://www.amazon.com") > -1) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = affiliate;
    }
}
readXML()
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
          body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 75%;
          }
          #status {
            /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
            white-space: normal;
            text-align: center;
            width: 200px;
            height: 225px;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 400px;
            word-wrap: normal;
          }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="demo"></table>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your XML to JSON with [jQuery XML to JSON Plugin](https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/). As result you will get a Javascript object with all properties:

```
{"merchant":{"domain":"http://www.amazon.com","affiliate":"1","id":"1"}}
```

Complete sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jquery-xml2json-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var 
            xml,
            json;

        xml = 

            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + 
            '<catalog>' + 
                '<merchant id="1">' + 
                '<domain>http://www.amazon.com</domain>' + 
                '<affiliate>1</affiliate>' + 
                '</merchant>' + 
            '</catalog>';

        json = $.xml2json(xml);

        alert(json.merchant.domain);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var affiliateData = {};

function loadUrlData(url, data, affiliateData) {
  var urlDomain = url.substring(url.indexOf('//') + 2);
  if (urlDomain.indexOf('/') > -1) {
    urlDomain = urlDomain.substring(0, urlDomain.indexOf('/'));
  }
  if (urlDomain.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    urlDomain = urlDomain.substring(0, urlDomain.indexOf('?'));
  }

  lastIndexOfDot = urlDomain.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (lastIndexOfDot < 0) {
    return;
  }


  do {
    affiliateData[urlDomain] = data;
    urlDomain = urlDomain.slice(urlDomain.indexOf('.') + 1);
  } while (urlDomain.indexOf('.') > -1);
};
function getAffiliateData(url, affiliateData) {
  var urlDomain = url.substring(url.indexOf('//') + 2);
  if (urlDomain.indexOf('/') > -1) {
    urlDomain = urlDomain.substring(0, urlDomain.indexOf('/'));
  }
  if (urlDomain.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    urlDomain = urlDomain.substring(0, urlDomain.indexOf('?'));
  }

  lastIndexOfDot = urlDomain.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (lastIndexOfDot < 0) {
    return 'none';
  }
  do {
    for (domain in affiliateData) {
      if (domain == urlDomain) {
        return affiliateData[domain];
      }
    }
    urlDomain = urlDomain.slice(urlDomain.indexOf('.') + 1);
  } while (urlDomain.indexOf('.') > -1);

  return 'none';
};

var url = 'http://www.amazon.com?asdf=/a/b/c';
var url2 = 'http://www.yahoo.com?asdf=/a/b/c';

loadUrlData('http://www.amazon.com?asdf=/a/b/c', 'data amazon', affiliateData);
loadUrlData('http://www.yahoo.com?asdf=/a/b/c', 'data yahoo', affiliateData);

alert(getAffiliateData(url, affiliateData));
alert(getAffiliateData(url2, affiliateData));
```